# Generate random value in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, random

```
{
  "description": "Appname",
  "name": "appname",
  "partnerProfile":  {
    "email": "aa@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Jobin",
    "partnerName": "app"
  }
}
```

I am passing the following body in a json file. How do I generate random value(time stamp) for `partnerName` for different test run. 
I am using Newman to run the script

```
Newman run Automation.json -e Dev.json -r html
```

Comment: strictly speaking, you can't; json is only static data. you need to alter the object after it's parsed, which depends completely on the runtime. you might not be able to alter your runtime, which means you need to use something else to alter the JSON (ie hard-code the random digits) before feeding it to what you're doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating good random data in Javascript is tricky.  How it works is different from browsers to node.js.  You can take a look at the uuid javascript library, which works both on node and browsers and generates random identifiers for this sort of thing.

That goes through each of the possible places where your random number generator might live

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid